# SyntaxError: Value expected (char 1)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, math.js

I'm trying to make a `!calculate` command in Discord.js v12.
I'm using [mathjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs) and this is my current code:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
    if(!msg.content.startsWith('!')) return;

    const args = msg.content.split(/[\ ]/g);
    const cmd = args[0].slice(1).toLowerCase();

    switch (cmd) {
        case 'calculate':
        case 'calc':
            if(!args[0]) return msg.channel.send('Please input a calculation.');

            let resp;
            try {
                resp = math.evaluate(args.join(''));
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

            const membed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#ffaa00')
                .setTitle('Math Calculation')
                 .addField('Input', `\`\`\`css\n${args.slice(1).join(' ')}\`\`\``)
                .addField('Output', `\`\`\`css\n${resp}\`\`\``);

            msg.channel.send(membed);
            break;
```

However, I get the following console error:

```
SyntaxError: Value expected (char 1)
    at createSyntaxError (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1705:17)
    at parseEnd (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1669:13)
    at parseParentheses (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1655:12)
    at parseNumber (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1626:12)
    at parseObject (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1607:12)
    at parseMatrix (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1532:12)
    at parseSingleQuotesString (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1433:12)
    at parseDoubleQuotesString (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1382:12)
    at parseSymbol (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1270:12)
    at parseCustomNodes (D:\Documents\test\Node.js\Discord.js\calculate\node_modules\mathjs\lib\expression\parse.js:1239:12) {
  char: 1
}
```

The embed looks like this:

[image: embed]

Comment: What is the content of args ?

Comment: My command handler is:
```
    if(!msg.content.startsWith('!')) return;
    const args = msg.content.split(/[\ ]/g);
    const cmd = args[0].slice(1).toLowerCase();
    switch (cmd) {
```
If thats what ur after?

Comment: No, I was asking the value of `args` at runtime when the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling the `args` array incorrectly. There are 2 issues:

1. `args[0]` needs to be changed to `args[1]`, as `args[0]` is
   referencing the command, not the calculation.

   ```js
   if(!args[0]) return msg.channel.send('Please input a calculation.');
   // should become
   if(!args[1]) return msg.channel.send('Please input a calculation.');
   ```
2. `args.join('')` needs to be changed to `args.slice(1).join('')`, so that it only contains the calculation and not the command at the start.

   ```js
   resp = math.evaluate(args.join(''));
   // should become
   resp = math.evaluate(args.slice(1).join(''));
   ```